# ROS2 managed node: how to get the exception type and message in the error handler

Tags: ros, ros2, rosnode, ros-humble

ROS2 provides a new improved type of ROS node called [lifecycle-managed node](https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html).

These nodes can transition from one machine state to another after a user request or some other event, such as an exception.

When an exception is thrown during a managed node transition, the state machine goes into the `ErrorProcessing` state, and the `on_error callback is called, as shown [here](https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html). So far so good.

My question is: I would like to know the exception type and message inside the `on_error` callback. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how?

By looking at the API of the lifecycle-managed node, I was not able to figure out how to get any information about the exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I am trying to handle errors thrown by a hardware interface, and I need to determine the kind of error that produced the `on_error` call.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/23570)

Comment: @JosephCarpinelli Unfortunately I did not find an answer. This is still an open problem for me. Please consider upvoting it so that it might be answered quickly.